# Sql correct filter for floats values in string column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have table invoices and there is column 'total' varchar(255). There are values like these: "500.00", "5'199.00", "129.60", "1.00" and others. 
I need select records and filter by total column. For example, find records where total is not more than 180.

I tried this:

```
SELECT total from invoices WHERE invoices.total <= '180'
```

But in result there are :

```
125.25
100.50
1593.55 - not correct
4'799.00 - not correct
1.00
-99.00
2406.52 -not correct
```

How can I fix it and write correct filter for this column? Thanks!

Comment: What is "5'199.00"?

Comment: you have to convert `total ` to number if not you make a string compare

Answer (score 1):

You can use cast() function to convert it in float

```
SELECT total from invoices WHERE cast(invoices.total as decimal(16,2)) <= 180
```

Comment: Cast will convert `4'799.00` to 4.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you storing numbers as strings?  That is a fundamental problem with your data model, and you should fix it.

Sometimes, we are stuck with other people's really, really, really bad decisions.  If that is the case, you can attempt to solve this with explicit conversion:

```
SELECT i.total 
FROM invoices i
WHERE CAST(REPLACE(i.total, '''', '') as DECIMAL(20, 4)) <= 180;
```

Note that this will return an error if you have other unexpected characters in your totals.

Comment: Thanks. String because there must be saved  format for total as 1'500.00  and others, cant save it as float.

Comment: @ForstackForstack storing decimals in string is just very very very plain wrong when you calculate on these strings the results can and will not be precise not something you want to have in a invoice system

Comment: @ForstackForstack you must learn to format the results on the front end.

Comment: @ForstackForstack totally agree with comments above. You have to save prices in number format in DB. If you need a specific format for showing prices or if you receive them in specific format - you can just transform them.

Answer (score 0):

If the string starts with a number, then contains non-numeric characters, you can use the [`CAST()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) function or convert it to a numeric implicitly by adding a `0`:

```
SELECT CAST('1234abc' AS UNSIGNED); -- 1234
SELECT '1234abc'+0; -- 1234
```

To extract numbers out of an *arbitrary* string you could add a custom [function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/adding-functions.html) like [this](https://ushastry.blogspot.com.by/2009/10/mysql-extract-numbers-out-of-string.html):

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION `ExtractNumber`(in_string VARCHAR(50)) 
RETURNS INT
NO SQL
BEGIN
    DECLARE ctrNumber VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE finNumber VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE sChar VARCHAR(1);
    DECLARE inti INTEGER DEFAULT 1;

    IF LENGTH(in_string) > 0 THEN
        WHILE(inti <= LENGTH(in_string)) DO
            SET sChar = SUBSTRING(in_string, inti, 1);
            SET ctrNumber = FIND_IN_SET(sChar, '0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9'); 
            IF ctrNumber > 0 THEN
                SET finNumber = CONCAT(finNumber, sChar);
            END IF;
            SET inti = inti + 1;
        END WHILE;
        RETURN CAST(finNumber AS UNSIGNED);
    ELSE
        RETURN 0;
    END IF;    
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Once the function is defined, you can use it in your query:

```
SELECT total from invoices WHERE ExtractNumber(invoices.total) <= 180
```